# Как сверстать кружки с текстом вокруг круга?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: кружки с текстом вокруг круга]

Как можно реализовать такой элемент?

Comment: Что-то я не понял логику ваших действий. Вам дали ответ на svg, вы приняли его, зачем убирать тег svg? Примите пожалуйста, к сведению, - разместив что-то на stackoverflow и получив ответ,- это уже не ваша единоличная собственность, а достояние всего сообщества

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle{
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle-item{
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle-item-1{
  top: 0; left: 10px;
}
.circle-item-2{
  top: 0; right: 10px;
}
.circle-item-3{
  top: 50%; right: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px
}
.circle-item-4{
  bottom: 0; right: 10px;
}
.circle-item-5{
  bottom: 0; left: 10px;
}
.circle-item-6{
  top: 50%; left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px
}


.circle-item > span{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; right: calc(100% + 15px);
  text-align: right;
  width: 300%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.circle-item:nth-of-type(2) > span,
.circle-item:nth-of-type(3) > span,
.circle-item:nth-of-type(4) > span{
  right: auto;
  left: calc(100% + 15px);
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle-item circle-item-1"><span>text</span></div>
  <div class="circle-item circle-item-2"><span>text</span></div>
  <div class="circle-item circle-item-3"><span>text</span></div>
  <div class="circle-item circle-item-4"><span>text</span></div>
  <div class="circle-item circle-item-5"><span>text</span></div>
  <div class="circle-item circle-item-6"><span>text</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как поставить разный текст около кругов?

Comment: @Vova Terentev - добавил вариант с текстом

Answer (score 6):

Вариант на `SVG`, всё адаптивно, текст расположен с помощью атрибутов `X` & `Y`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <circle cx="95" cy="35" r="20" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <g fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
            <circle cx="105" cy="18" r="5" />
            <circle cx="85" cy="18" r="5" />
            <circle cx="115" cy="35" r="5" />
            <circle cx="75" cy="35" r="5" />
            <circle cx="105" cy="52" r="5" />
            <circle cx="85" cy="52" r="5" />
        </g>
        <g font-size="10px" font-family="Arial">
            <text x="45" y="20">Lorem</text>
            <text x="40" y="37">Ipsum</text>
            <text x="50" y="55">Dolor</text>
            <text x="115" y="55">Sit</text>
            <text x="122" y="37">Amet</text>
            <text x="120" y="20">Ist</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Делаю сайт без использования флекса, но поставлю правильный ответ)

Comment: @VovaTerentev, это лишь для наглядного примера:)

Comment: St1myL - ты крут.

Comment: @MursalovOleg, преувеличение, каждый желающий изучить `SVG` сможет сделать такое. Если вы интересуетесь `SVG`, тогда приходите в чат - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat